# trying to initiate googlemap with javascript getting permission denied to access property name

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to initiate google map with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latitude;
        var longitude;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': '{{Session::get('location')}}'}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
          } else {
            alert("Something got wrong " + status);
          }
        });
```

and directly after that code I have this

```
        function initMap() {
            console.log('initMap');
          var myLatLng = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};
```

Problem arrises when I do

> var myLatLng = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};

I get this

> Error: Permission denied to access property "name" jquery.min.js (rad 2, kol 31089)

If I hardcode lat and lng using nubers like

> myLatLng = {lat: 15.000, lng: 15.000};

then it works, but not if I try to use variables which I need to use

Comment: The geocoder is asynchronous, you need to use the values in the callback function when/where they are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting your latitude and longitude values, in some cases they may get initialized as strings. i.e:

```
var myLatLng = {lat: parseFloat(latitude), lng: parseFloat(longitude)};
```

Also, if latitude and longitude aren't being set you can try calling initMap as parameters:

```
 geocoder.geocode( { 'address': '{{Session::get('location')}}'}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            initMap(latitude, longitude);
          } else {
            alert("Something got wrong " + status);
          }
 });
```

Where initMap is now:

```
function initMap(latitude, longitude) {
    console.log('initMap');
    var myLatLng = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};
    ...
}
```

Comment: it's not that, I discovered that variables inside anonymous function are not the same scope as outside of function, so long and ltd never get set, I do not know how to set them and return them outside of anonymous function. do you know?

Comment: Maybe this is an async problem, does it work to set parameters for initMap and call it when you set lat and long values?